# SSLEngine with blocking IO

Tags: java, ssl, nio

From the SSLEngine documentation: "By separating the SSL/TLS abstraction from the I/O transport mechanism, the SSLEngine can be used for a wide variety of I/O types, such as non-blocking I/O (polling), selectable non-blocking I/O, Socket and the traditional Input/OutputStreams, local ByteBuffers or byte arrays, .."  Would using SSLEngine with regular Sockets, and blocking channels, any better compared to using SSLSocket for blocking IO.

Comment: No. It's network-bound. I tested this extensively some years ago. The belief that NIO has better performance is in general a myth. What it does have, or at least what it was designed to have, is better scalability. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Marginally, yes. NIO is not only about non-blocking IO. It also brought:

- A higher lever API, based on wrapped buffers (ByteBuffers), instead of just byte arrays.
- "Scattering" and "gathering" API, that is, the ability to use more than one sequential buffer in the same IO operation.
- Direct IO: the use "direct" ByteBuffers, that can live out of the heap.

The last point has very concrete general performance implications, because when using heap-based arrays/buffers, the JVM does an extra copy of any array sent in a native call, to facilitate synchronization with the garbage collector. This is avoided with native buffers, which can reduce garbage collection overhead significantly.

That said, SSLEngine has huge usability problems, as using it correctly is *seriously* hard, in particular much harder than using the good old SSLSocket.

Fortunately, [this library](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel) allows to use SSLEngine with a ByteChannel interface, doing all the heavy lifing around SSLEngine (Disclaimer: I am the main author).